# Reducing loop time of a for loop python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling for a while now with the following. I've got a dataset that contains hardware_serials and timestamps.

```
 hardware_serial  ...    Timestamp           
0    00053        ...  2020-10-26 16:04:41
1    77684             2020-10-26 16:02:23
2    00053             2020-10-26 15:59:41
3    77684             2020-10-26 15:57:23
```

The goal is to filter out rows that have a timestamp that's between 4-7 minutes later than the first row of that hardware_serial. There are also more rows with that hardware_serial, only those are a couple hours later and I'm only interested in comparing two messages within 4-7 minutes in order to filter out duplicates.

```
rawdata['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(rawdata['date'] + ' ' + rawdata['time'])
        newdf = rawdata
    for x in range(len(rawdata.index)):
        for y in range(len(rawdata.index)):
                if rawdata['hardware_serial'].iloc[x] == rawdata['hardware_serial'].iloc[y]:
                    if y != x:
                            if a.iloc[x] - a.iloc[y] > timedelta(minutes=0):
                                if a.iloc[x] - a.iloc[y] <= timedelta(minutes=7):
                                    if x in newdf.index:
                                        newdf = newdf.drop(x)
```

This loop is functioning correctly, only it already takes 15 seconds for 600 rows. Then you could imagine what it takes for 10E3 rows.

The thing is, the duplicate rows only have to be checked with a couple of rows below, let's say maximum 20 rows below. Because after 20 rows enough time will have passed and it will never be in the 5 min frame anymore.

Hence, I thought of creating a nested loop that compares a value of `rawdata['Timestamp'].iloc(x)` with another value that's 1,2,3,...,20 rows below AKA the inner for loop with the parameter 'y'.
I have a hard time explaining this correctly, so my idea is shown below.

```
newdf = rawdata
for x in range(0,len(rawdata.index)-20):
    for y in range(1,20):
        if rawdata['hardware_serial'].iloc[x] == rawdata['hardware_serial'].iloc[x+y]:
                    if a.iloc[x] - a.iloc[x+y] > timedelta(minutes=0):
                        if a.iloc[x] - a.iloc[x+y] <= timedelta(minutes=7):
                            if x+y in newdf.index:
                                print(x + y)
                                print(a.iloc[x] - a.iloc[x + y])
                                newdf = newdf.drop(x+y)
```

However, when I execute this nested for loop, everytime I change the range of y, the dataframe changes of size. So this is not working properly. Unfortunately, I don't see how.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Likely a self merge and query helps.

Comment: Why not create a `delta` column to contain minutes since `x`, then run a boolean filter for `delta between 4 and 7`?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. Minutes since x is variable for every row. So, for example row 1 is 4 minutes from row 2, but row 1 is also 8 minutes from row 3, etc.. How would it be possible to store all those values in one column? @S3DEV